# L'expression: J'en ai ras le bol

Tags: expressions

Que signifie l'expression "**En avoir ras le bol**" et quand est ce qu'on le dit ?
J'en ai beaucoup entendu parlé. Est ce que  c'est pareil que "En avoir marre" ?

Comment: Tu as tout compris.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Voilà un lien décrivant l'origine de "ras-le-bol" (qui s'écrit avec des tirets d'ailleurs) : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ras-le-bol

Le sens est très proche, sinon identique, à celui de "j'en ai marre", en plus fort ; quelqu'un qui en a ras-le-bol en a encore plus marre que quelqu'un qui en a marre !

Une autre différence est que l'emploi de ras-le-bol est plus large : on peut parler d'un ras-le-bol, (un ras-le-bol général par exemple, qui voudra dire qu'une majorité de personnes en ont marre).

Et c'est aussi un peu plus vulgaire, en avoir marre est un argot plus poli et moins incisif (moins 'agressif').

Comment: Les images évoquées par 'en avoir ras-le-bol' en français et 'be fed up' en anglais semblent toutes les deux dériver d'une idée d'excès alimentaire!

Comment: Je ne connais pas l'origine de 'be fed up', mais dans 'ras-le-bol', le bol n'avait à la base rien d'alimentaire .... :)